# Show tagged user names on image Like Instagram using Swift

Tags: swift

I'm creating an app where user can post a feed(Image/Video) like Instagram. Now, i need to get over the feature of Tagging Peoples same like Instagram.

For example: User can tag peoples to photo before making new post and once it available in recent feeds listing, anyone can tap on photo and see whom are tagged with that photo.

Is there any effective and simple way to implement this thing?

Any comment or link for refer further will be surely helpful.

Comment: I don't see any difficulties, is your tagging system automatic or the user enters himself people's name ?

Comment: user search name and tag him

Comment: Do you have any specific examples? check out [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information

Comment: If you are able to add a feed, I don't see any difficulties to add an edit text and enter people name to tag them